# rosrun can't find camera1394_node or camera1394_nodelet

Tags: ros, catkin, camera1394, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS Indigo on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 (`Linux turtlebot 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:42 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`)

The only ROS package is the 1394-master branch as downloaded from github: https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394

When I try to run the camera1394_node, ros can't find the executable:

```
turtlebot@turtlebot:~/ros$ rosrun camera1394 camera1394_node
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named camera1394_node below /home/turtlebot/ros/src/camera1394-master
```

Its the same with camera1394_nodelet:

```
turtlebot@turtlebot:~/ros$ rosrun camera1394 camera1394_nodelet
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named camera1394_nodelet below /home/turtlebot/ros/src/camera1394-master
```

I don't see any errors when I catkin_make:

```
$ cd ~/ros/ && catkin_make
Base path: /home/turtlebot/ros
Source space: /home/turtlebot/ros/src
Build space: /home/turtlebot/ros/build
Devel space: /home/turtlebot/ros/devel
Install space: /home/turtlebot/ros/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/turtlebot/ros/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/turtlebot/ros/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/turtlebot/ros/install" in "/home/turtlebot/ros/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/turtlebot/ros/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.6") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/turtlebot/ros/build/test_results
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.9
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - camera1394
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'camera1394'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(camera1394-master)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.26") 
-- checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   found libdc1394-2, version 2.2.1
-- camera1394: 0 messages, 2 services
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/turtlebot/ros/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j4" in "/home/turtlebot/ros/build"
####
Scanning dependencies of target _camera1394_generate_messages_check_deps_SetCameraRegisters
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target _camera1394_generate_messages_check_deps_GetCameraRegisters
Scanning dependencies of target camera1394_gencfg
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  4%] Generating dynamic reconfigure files from cfg/Camera1394.cfg: /home/turtlebot/ros/devel/include/camera1394/Camera1394Config.h /home/turtlebot/ros/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camera1394/cfg/Camera1394Config.py
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  4%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  4%] [  4%] Built target _camera1394_generate_messages_check_deps_GetCameraRegisters
Built target _camera1394_generate_messages_check_deps_SetCameraRegisters
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target camera1394_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target camera1394_generate_messages_lisp
[  4%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 12%] [ 12%] Generating Lisp code from camera1394/SetCameraRegisters.srv
Generating C++ code from camera1394/SetCameraRegisters.srv
Scanning dependencies of target camera1394_generate_messages_py
Generating reconfiguration files for Camera1394 in camera1394
[ 16%] Wrote header file in /home/turtlebot/ros/devel/include/camera1394/Camera1394Config.h
Generating Python code from SRV camera1394/SetCameraRegisters
[ 20%] [ 20%] Built target camera1394_gencfg
Generating Lisp code from camera1394/GetCameraRegisters.srv
[ 25%] Generating Python code from SRV camera1394/GetCameraRegisters
[ 29%] Generating C++ code from camera1394/GetCameraRegisters.srv
[ 29%] Built target camera1394_generate_messages_lisp
[ 33%] Generating Python srv __init__.py for camera1394
[ 33%] Built target camera1394_generate_messages_py
[ 33%] Built target camera1394_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target camera1394_generate_messages
Scanning dependencies of target camera1394_nodelet
Scanning dependencies of target camera1394_node
[ 33%] Built target camera1394_generate_messages
[ 37%] [ 41%] [ 45%] Building CXX object camera1394-master/src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_node.dir/dev_camera1394.cpp.o
Building CXX object camera1394-master/src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_node.dir/camera1394_node.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object camera1394-master/src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_node.dir/driver1394.cpp.o
Building CXX object camera1394-master/src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_nodelet.dir/nodelet.cpp.o
[ 54%] Building CXX object camera1394-master/src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_node.dir/features.cpp.o
[ 58%] Building CXX object camera1394-master/src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_node.dir/format7.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object camera1394-master/src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_nodelet.dir/driver1394.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object camera1394-master/src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_node.dir/modes.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object camera1394-master/src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_node.dir/registers.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object camera1394-master/src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_node.dir/trigger.cpp.o
[ 79%] Building CXX object camera1394-master/src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_nodelet.dir/dev_camera1394.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object camera1394-master/src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_nodelet.dir/features.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable /home/turtlebot/ros/devel/lib/camera1394/camera1394_node
[ 83%] Built target camera1394_node
[ 87%] Building CXX object camera1394-master/src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_nodelet.dir/format7.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object camera1394-master/src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_nodelet.dir/modes.cpp.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object camera1394-master/src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_nodelet.dir/registers.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object camera1394-master/src/nodes/CMakeFiles/camera1394_nodelet.dir/trigger.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library /home/turtlebot/ros/devel/lib/libcamera1394_nodelet.so
[100%] Built target camera1394_nodelet
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192286/rosrun-can%27t-find-camera1394_node-or-camera1394_nodelet/) by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2014-09-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on 2014-09-10**:
Tutorial fail:
`source ./devel/setup.bash`
//\ running this allows me to now run camera1394_node, the nodlet is still missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am on vacation until next week.

This driver was recently released as an Indigo package. You can install it this way:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-camera1394
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on 2014-09-12**:
Worked like a charm.